# How to find whether the OS running is on virtual machine or physical using Sigar API

Tags: javascript, sigar

How to find whether the OS running is on virtual machine or physical using Sigar API. I am using Sigar Api, I am able to get all cpu related info, but not the OS is virtual or physical